# Test uniqueness with rpec and capybara - not passing when error looks right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a Taxonomy model with the following:

```
# Mass assignable fields
attr_accessible :name, :classification, :is_shown

# Add validation
validates :name,           :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :classification, :presence => true
```

Using rspec + capybara, I want to test the uniqueness validator.

```
Taxonomy.create(:name => 'foo', :classification => 'activity').save!(:validate => false)
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:classification) }
```

This test fails with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:classification) }
Expected errors to include "has already been taken" when name is set to "foo", got errors: ["name has already been taken (\"foo\")", "classification is not included in the list (:activitz)"] (with different value of classification)
 # ./spec/models/taxonomy_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It appears to me the test should be passing.  What am I missing?

Comment: Right off the hope I'm wondering, if your test is saying that the name is unique scoped to the classification, why is that not stated in your model? It should look like this: `validates :name, :uniqueness => { :scope => :classification }` for the uniqueness part.

Comment: MrDanA - I added the .scoped_to() in the test because failing to do so causes a nil value to be passed for :classification, which makes the test fail for violating the not-null constraint on the db column.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Capybara question since this is dealing with a model spec. I'm assuming you're using the [shoulda matchers gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) in order to utilize these special `ActiveRecord` validation matchers.

Given a model like your example:

```
class Taxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,           :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :classification, :presence => true
end
```

You will have the following spec:

```
describe Taxonomy do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:classification) }
end
```

However, if you really want the uniqueness of your name field to be scoped to classification:

```
class Taxonomy < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,           :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :scope => :classification }
  validates :classification, :presence => true
end
```

...and the following spec:

```
describe Taxonomy do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:classification) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:classification) }
end
```